# How do you contact Hollywood directors?

Tags: publishing, screenwriting

1. What legitimate websites or methods can I use to contact a few directors about making a movie from my book?
2. How many pitches for movies does a director receive? What percentage of their mail or electronic communications does this represent?
3. Do you need to send something to a director along with your book, like a query letter for publishers?

Sorry, I couldn't find a better tag for this.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about getting a job and getting the attention of celebrities, not writing.

Comment: @wetcircuit I disagree.  Getting a writing job is on topic (having a screenplay picked up is a job/publication) and pitching to directors is not that different from pitching to publishers, which is also on topic.  Now, this question is way too broad, but it's not off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a service called [scriptblaster](http://www.scriptblaster.com/). For a small fee (less than $100), you can submit a one page "query letter" which they will "blast" to many parties on a weekly basis. I have actually received one inquiry, out of about 600 blasts.

Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

The practical answer is via six degrees of separation. The film industry is well served by a wealth of established script and story writers. Short of stalking or kidnapping, there's virtually no way of getting your script in front of a producer or director.

In reality, they will only at scripts handed to them by 'people they know.' This person could be an agent, a known scriptwriter, an established actor, or their kids' babysitter, as long as it's somebody they know.

Sorry, it's not better news.

Comment: The only other option i see outside of what you mention is it being the flavor of the year... AKA Hunger Games, GoT, Twilight, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. Directors do not of themselves decide to make a movie. This is decided by the studios. The studios will then usually approach directors to see if they want to direct said movie, based on the script.

Basically because they're the ones that have to put up the money to make a movie. Since movies cost many, many millions of dollars to make they are not unsurprisingly cautious about turning any book into a moving picture.

Yes you can approach directors, but since they usually make their decisions based on movie scripts. In general, they won't interested in reading every book that comes their way before deciding to make a movie out of it. Certainly some directors do decide to make a movie based on a book they have read. These directors may also write the script for their own movies. They still have to go to the studios to get the money raised.

Sadly it looks unprofessional for a writer to approach a movie director and say I have written a book and I'd like you to make a movie based on it. Being unprofessional will kill the project stone dead before it gets out the door.

Being professional, you should either write your own movie script based on your book and join the Hollywood scriptwriters' guild or possibly approach a script writer who can determine if your book (a) can be made into a movie script, and (b) is even worth being turned into a movie script. Basically a book by itself won't sell its way into becoming a movie. Someone has to write that script.

Next you will need an agent to hawk your script around the studios and even to movie directors and producers. never forget about producers, they're the money people behind the scenes. Having an agent is professional, without one you will get nowhere.

Remember you are competing against battalions of other hopeful writers who believe, usually wrongly, that if they can approach a movie director it will get their book, magically, transformed into a movie. That might happen in a movie, this is reality.

Oh, yes, there is one way you can get your book made into a Hollywood movie. Write a bestseller that sells millions and which by its very nature demands that it should be made into a movie. Then the movie people will come to you. So write the best book you can and hope it's pure gold movie material.

Forget about chasing Hollywood directors. Find out everything you can about the movie industry. Write your movie script. Join the screenwriters' guild. Be professional always. Hire an agent. But first write the best book ever.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most important thing to know is that directors and producers worry about unintentionally using a movie idea which another person owns the copyright for.

Consider two scenarios:

1. A submitter submits an idea which he ripped off from his neighbor.
   (Or: uses a character from another literary work).
2. A submitter sends a query letter which the director rejects or
   ignores. Then, the director makes a movie with a similar concept.

In these two instances, the director is exposing himself or herself to liability. For that reason, they are careful who they accept ideas from.

On the other hand, agented material is more likely to be vetted -- the agent has probably already verified  copyright status. For that reason, getting the agent to submit it is probably smarter.

That said, so much of moviemaking today is informal. (I say this as somebody who has nothing to do with that industry). It may very well help to distribute your concept or pitch liberally to film producers in nontraditional ways. But doing it through agents protect your interest and the directors' interest.

**UPDATE:** Given that you are the author of the literary work, my suggestion might not be relevant -- especially if you already published the book yourself. A published book is generally good evidence that the author owns the copyright. Nevertheless, I think directors are reluctant to consider film pitches from unfamiliar sources.